# How to get the result from fraction without rounding up in Thymeleaf

Tags: numbers, format, thymeleaf, fractions

I am trying to get the relation between the height and width from image and then multiply by a fixed width to resize a picture using Thymeleaf.

For it, I saved the height and width in a java object called `g`. Using a fixed `width: 270px` I want to scale the height using the relation between the sized saved doing that:

`th:style="'height:' + ${(g.height / g.width) * 270} +';`

The saved and original size is: `int height = 286` and `int width = 423`.
So the fraction's result should be `286/423 = 0.67`.
But the problem is that this fraction `g.height / g.width` is giving me 0 as result.

How can I obtain decimals from this fraction? I tried with `{#numbers.formatDecimal()}` but not results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both `width` & `height` are integers, it's doing integer division.  Either store them as `float`/`double`  on the object itself, or convert them to doubles in the expression.

```
 th:style="'height:' + ${((0.0 + g.height) / g.width) * 270} +'px;'"
```